# Please explain me the meaning of this review audit case

Tags: support, review-audits

In rare occasions I disagree with what review audit tests suggest, but usually those disagreements are not that critical, but this one seems rather blatant to me, so I require some assistance here.

The question is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39485341/rctwebsocket-does-not-build-on-xcode-8-ios10):

> After update to XCode 8, I have a problem for build RN project about `RCTWebSocket`. Anyone have a problem?

What I can see about this question is

1. It is not specific: it doesn't provide an MCVE whatsoever
2. It is poorly worded: the direct answer would be either "yes, me too" or "nope"

Now, before looking at the context, let's consider my behaviour. I wasn't going to flag it or downvote, but taking the problems I mentioned above into account I was going to kindly suggest improvements about the wording of the question (2) and to add an MCVE to make it reproducible (1). But the standart audit window suggested "Your review was inappropriate." once I sent the comment.

Ok, when I see that the post has many upvotes, I suspect that the issue was really common and many people just were about to ask similar questions and the post got +18. Probably for those who used `RCTWebSocket` on XCode 8 the issue was pretty clear.

Still, I can't see how this audit evaluates my review. I have 2 main questions:

1. Are there some pointers that I missed? Is my review really that inappropriate?
2. How the audit tests are created? The audit message always sais that they are "designed", but for me this situation looks more like audit system just grabbed a high-score question and accused me just because I tried to comment it.

Comment: "_audit system just grabbed a high-score question and accused me just because I tried to comment it._" yes that's exactly true.  This is a bad audit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every time some part of the iOS toolchain changes, a crapload of people post questions about stuff that breaks. They're often not very well-written questions, but they don't *have* to be: everyone and their dog is getting the same errors, so as long as they're somewhat searchable and manage to attract a working solution, others find them and upvote in appreciation of the fact that they're not alone facing the cold, cruel reality of the situation.

...Of course, this wreaks havoc with the audit-selection algorithms.

I've closed and merged that question with a better-written one, so it shouldn't be offered as an audit again.